# Run sc command in InstallShield installer

Tags: windows, installation, installshield

I have an sc command that I would like to run using the Visual Studio 2012 InstallShield version in the "After Register Product" custom action. I have opted for "New Exe" for the executing action. I've selected "File Exists on Target Computer" for the source location. For the "File Location" I've entered "[SystemFolder]". For the "File Name and Command Line" I have, approximately,

> sc.exe create ABC binPath= "[INSTALLDIR]abc.exe"
>   DisplayName= "ABC Service" start= auto

. When I run the installer it fails. I'm at a loss as to the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had similar problems in the past. Solved in another way, CA type: `Deferred execution in system context`, Working Directory `SystemFolder` :

```
cmd.exe /c "[WindowsFolder]system32\sc.exe delete [SERVICENAME]"
```